# The passing of a string (incl. regex parameters) to a block of code

Tags: regex, ruby, string, gsub

A string of length 4 letters or more needs to be returned in the following format:

"#{firstLetter}#{string.length-2}#{lastLetter}"

InputString = stackoverflow

ExpectedString = s11w

Here is the code that results in the correct expected output.

```
string.gsub /(\w)(\w+{2})(\w)/ do |word|       
      "#{$1}#{word.length-2}#{$3}"        
end
```

I sort of get what's going on here but don't understand the exact relation between the regex and the use of $1 and $3. Sorta get it... but not enough to be able to use it in my own way for new problems.

Comment: It's very simple: `$N` means "content of the N-th capture group from the match". It's in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables), BTW.

Comment: The regexp is weird though. Why `\w+{2}`? It works, but... Weeeird. And depending on how the engine is implemented, might be inefficient. I'd write `\w{2,}`...

Comment: Missed it in the docs. Thanks for the help with my pretty stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, you have 3 capturing groups: `\w`, `\w+{2}` and again `\w`. When you later say `$N` (where `N` is some number), you are actually referring to the capturing group from the regex.

The `String#gsub` methods populates these variables for you ([Ruby doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-gsub)).

Comment: So .gsub finds the matching criteria in the string as per the requirements of the regex and replaces each match with that specified in the string literal. Correct?

Comment: @Rey in the block form, `gsub` replaces each match with the block's result.

Comment: @Rey yes, but it's not each _match_, it's each **capturing group**. Following regex won't work: `/\w\w+{2}\w/`.